# How to render and display rich text editor data like Images, and code block etc with express and mongoDB and show it on frontend

Tags: mongodb, express, backend, mern

I am creating a **full stack blog application** but I am confused how can i render **rich text editor data** on the backend using express and mongoDB Just like this stackover flow  text editor. **Most important thig is how can find Images of text editor data and push it on cloudinary.** help me out please

Answer (score 0):

First, you should choose what editor you would like to use. One popular open source editor is [Quill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quill) for example.

After you implement it in your frontend, you should listen to the events on the editor instance (`image.added`, `image.removed`...) and based on that you can upload or delete your images from the cloud.

There is also an option to store images encoded in the HTML so you don't have to upload them to cloud at all, but that is not the good practice since it will significantly increase the payload of the HTML.

After you are done with the article, the output HTML from the editor can be saved in the MongoDB, and later you can fetch it and display it in the client side.